# Can I change to a fontcolor that looks like it is greyed out?

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

I would like to know if it is possible to force excel to show a font formatting that is normally used for greyed out text?

Comment: Unlclear what you mean. Of course you can set your text in excel to _any_ color you like, grey being one of the choices.

Comment: Well, a greyed out font is not just a grey font, it has this little white edge to it that makes it look like it is beveled. I was just wondering if there is a VB way to force that specific font formatting onto a string, so I can use it on a normal piece of text in a cell, not an object.

Comment: I also asked this on StackOverflow, as it may be more appropriate there